# I can't create a folder in project internal directory

Tags: java, android, file, android-studio, filenotfoundexception

I want to create a **txt** file in the **`"Ocenki"`** folder

I wrote a code that should be written to the **stringbuffer** file:

```
try {
    FileOutputStream write =  new FileOutputStream(
        new File(
            context.getFilesDir() 
            + File.separator + "Ocenki" 
            + File.separator + url + ".txt")
    );

    String temp_write = stringBuffer.toString();

    write.write(temp_write.getBytes());
    write.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException p) {
    p.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException a) {
    a.printStackTrace();
}
```

Method **`context.getFilesDir()`** returns: **`"/data/user/0/com.example.kos/files"`**

Variable `url` contains: `"2019 - 2020"`

Error occurs in the code:

```
FileNotFoundException  
"java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.example.kos/files/2019 - 2020.txt  
(No such file or directory)"
```

What do I do wrong?

UPD:

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.kos"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.1.1">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    ...

</manifest>
```

Here is a request for permissions:

```
 if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context,new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},3);
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
               ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},3);
```

Comment: Have you added Read Write storage permission?

Comment: "FileNotFoundException "java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.example.kos/files/url (No such file or directory)", Is this exactly copied from the trace. I think the stack trace should have "/data/user/0/com.example.kos/files/Ocenki/2019 - 2020.txt"

Comment: If `context.getFilesDir()` returns `"/data/user/0/com.example.kos/files"`, `url` is a variable and its value is `"2019 - 2020"`, then why does your code try to access the (sub)directory `"/data/user/0/com.example.kos/files/url"`? Does it exist? Don't you want `"/data/user/0/com.example.kos/files/2019 - 2020"` instead?

Comment: what your txt file name ?

Comment: Try changing value of `url` from "2019 - 2020" to "2019-2020". Remove spaces.

Comment: Nik, yes; 
Aman jangra, deHaar I corrected the error text:
Kanzariya Hitesh "2019 - 2020.txt"

Comment: Rohit5k2, It didn't help

Comment: You should create the file if it doesn't exist. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24676655/2936153

Comment: @Rohit5k2 Maybe not. The text file should have been created using the same code.   Issue is with the path, maybe one of the directory from the path is missing. Is the Ocenki folder present ?

Comment: Rohit5k2, Thank you, it solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Here you go,

```
try{

  System.out.println("File Path = " + MainApplication.getFileDirectory() + "/Ocenki" + "/" + fileName);
  File fileCreated = new File(MainApplication.getFileDirectory() + "/Ocenki" + "/" + fileName);
  if (fileCreated.exists()) {
    fileCreated.delete();
  }
  outputStream = new FileOutputStream(MainApplication.getFileDirectory() + "/Ocenki" + "/" + fileName);
  byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
  int read;

  while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
  }

  //inputStream.close();
  outputStream.flush();
  outputStream.close();
  }catch (IOException io){
  io.printStackTrace();
}



public static File getFileDirectory() {
 return filesDir;
}
```

As I used this class in application class you can use this method on any class based on it's context

```
 filesDir = MainApplication.this.getFilesDir();
```

Comment: Pass a File Name to this method